# NodeMCU: Can you call GPIO from the browser?

Tags: javascript, lua, gpio, nodemcu

I have a devkit running NodeMCU working great with fairly complex LUA & dynamically generated HTML.  I ran into the HTTP payload limit of 1440 bytes, so had to feed the HTTP server in chunks.

The end result is great, but the performance is not so great.  I'd like to improve the performance by directly accessing the pins of my devkit from JavaScript running in the browser.  That way, I don't have to refresh the page every time I click a button on the browser.

Is there a way to access the GPIO API from a browser running on the internet, using JavaScript?

Comment: My code is available on BitBucket:  git@bitbucket.org:haryadoon/nodemcu_lua_devkit.git

Comment: Kudos, you got the `socket:send()` right! Good we have that sample in our docs ;-)

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your question. This can be done with JavaScript (AJAX) and NodeMCU but you still need to implement a server socket of some sort on your devkit yourself.

Comment: Thanks, Marcel.  I believe I used your sample code to build my site.

Comment: Do you have some sample code I can use that would implement a server socket to listen on a different port for requests?  Would it be standard HTTP requests (GET, POST, etc)?

Comment: I'm now thinking I should create a lua function to listen on another TCP port, and reference that inside init.lua.  On "receive" then it would check the request data and return a single digit for the current GPIO status for the requested pin.